# Json ответ страницей

Tags: php, javascript, json

Есть такой код:

```
$('#myform').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $form = $('#myform');
    $.ajax({
        type: $form.attr('method'),
        url: $form.attr('action'),
        data: $form.serialize()
    }).done(function (dat) {
        var json = $.parseJSON(data);
        console.log(dat);
        if(!alert('Ваш номер заказа - '+dat.num+'. Также мы продублировали вам в СМС и на почту.')){

        }
        }).fail(function () {
            console.log('fail');
        });});
```

При выполнении этой функции ответом приходит нужное значение и весь код страницы. 
Таким образом отправляю данные обратно. NumZakaz - это id.

```
echo json_encode(array('num' => $model->NumZakaz));
```

Проблема заключается в том, что я получаю помимо json переменной, код самой страницы, из-за этого возникает ошибка парсинга.
Прошу помощи!

Comment: Поддержать вас?)

Comment: В чем состоит ваш вопрос?

Comment: `exit();` после вывода json напишите, подозреваю в этом проблема

Comment: Вангую, что серверный скрипт отправляет JSON, и дальше - "футер сайта". Решение: после отправки JSON на сервере сделайте `die;`. Если у вас PHP FastCGI, там есть еще одна команда "отключения от клиента", подзабыл, поищу

Comment: Скорей всего в url: $form.attr('action') адрес обычной страницы, которая возвращает шаблон+контент и имеет тип text/html. Надо либо в скрипте страницы определять вид запроса и возвращать контент без шаблона с нужным типом. Либо отправлять на отдельный скрипт, в котором нет вызова шаблона

Answer (score 1):

Необходимо было [заменить](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/868347/json-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%B9/868933#comment1406689_868347) `echo` на `return`.